# iText7 (.net) SignExternalSignatureContainer NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, digital-signature, nullreferenceexception, itext7

Im trying to create a `C#` Program that can Digitally Sign PDF Documents. For Including the Signature Element into the PDF I'm using `iText7`.
Now if I run the program without the debugger a `System.NullReferenceException` will be thrown and the program fails. But if I run the Program with the debugger the exception also occurs and the code continues and sign the PDF correctly...

Im not sure if this a problem of `iText7` or if I made a mistake or forgot something important while creating the signature field.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

**Exception**

> System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
> bei iText.Signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance.GetAppearance() in C:\Development\Others\itext7\itext\itext.sign\itext\signatures\PdfSignatureAppearance.cs:Zeile 584.
> bei iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.PreClose(IDictionary`2 exclusionSizes) in C:\Development\Others\itext7\itext\itext.sign\itext\signatures\PdfSigner.cs:Zeile 808.
> bei iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(IExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer, Int32 estimatedSize) in C:\Development\Others\itext7\itext\itext.sign\itext\signatures\PdfSigner.cs:Zeile 582.
> bei SignService.Engine.Core.PdfEngine.AddSignature(SignTask task) in C:\Development\Signature\SignService.Engine\Core\PdfEngine.cs:Zeile 122.

**My Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Add SignatureField to Pdf
/// and digitally sign it 
/// </summary>
public SignatureResult AddSignature(SignTask task)
{
    _logger.Info("Start Signing PDF");

    var prop = task.SignatureProperties;

    try
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(prop.Document));
        var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        var signer = new PdfSigner(reader, stream, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

        // set appearance
        var appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.SetReason(prop.SignReason)
                  .SetLocation(prop.SignLocation)
                  .SetContact(prop.SignContact);

        // set rendering mode
        switch (_settings.Pdf.RenderingMode)
        {
            case SignatureRenderingMode.Description:
                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
                break;
            case SignatureRenderingMode.Graphic:
                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
                break;
            case SignatureRenderingMode.GraphicAndDescription:
                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
                break;
            case SignatureRenderingMode.NameAndDescription:
                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
                break;
        }

        // set image
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_settings.Pdf.SignatureGraphicPath))
        {
            if (File.Exists(_settings.Pdf.SignatureGraphicPath))
            {
                var imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(_settings.Pdf.SignatureGraphicPath);
                appearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
            }
            else if (_settings.Pdf.RenderingMode == SignatureRenderingMode.GraphicAndDescription || _settings.Pdf.RenderingMode == SignatureRenderingMode.GraphicAndDescription)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create Signature Field.\nIf rendering mode is graphic or graphic and description, a signature image must be provided");
            }
        }

        // set visibility
        if (prop.Visible)
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle(prop.X, prop.Y, prop.Width, prop.Height);
            appearance.SetPageRect(rect);
            appearance.SetPageNumber(1); // todo create setting for this
        }

        signer.SetFieldName(_settings.Pdf.SignatureFieldName);

        // sign field
        var signatureContainer = new ExternalSignatureContainer(task, _settings.Ais);
        // **Exeption thrown here**
        signer.SignExternalContainer(signatureContainer, GetEstimatedSize(task.TimestampOnly));

        var tempResult = stream.ToArray();

        // set revocation info if active
        if (tempResult.Length > 0 && _settings.Ais.AddRevocationInfo)
        {
            tempResult = AddRevocationInfo(signatureContainer.Crl, signatureContainer.Ocsp, tempResult);
        }

        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        _logger.Info("Finished signing");

        // return sign result
        return tempResult.Length > 0 
          ? new SignatureResult
          {
               Message = "",
               Status = RequestStatus.Success,
               Document = stream.ToArray(),
               Id = prop.Id
          }
          : new SignatureResult
          {
               Message = "Failed to sign the Document",
               Status = RequestStatus.Failed,
               Document = null,
               Id = prop.Id
          };
    }
    catch (AisServiceException aisServiceException)
    {
        _logger.Error($"While requesting Signature an error occured: {aisServiceException.Message}", aisServiceException);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Error($"While creating signed pdf an error occured: {exception.Message}", exception);
        throw new PdfException($"While creating Signed Pdf an error Occured: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Settings:**

```
{
  "Pdf": {
    "Visible": true,
    "Position": {
      "X": 50,
      "Y": 50,
      "Height": 100,
      "Width": 200
    },
    "SignatureFieldName": "SignatureField",
    "SignatureGraphicPath": "",
    "RenderingMode": 1
  }
}
```

**Task:**

```
  "SignatureProperties": {
    "Id": "1",
    "Document": [DocumentAsByteArray],
    "Visible": true,
    "SignReason": "Test",
    "SignLocation": "Test",
    "SignContact": "Test",
    "Height": 100,
    "Width": 200,
    "X": 50,
    "Y": 50
  }
```

Comment: The issue occurs in `PdfSignatureAppearance.GetAppearance()`. Here the visualization of the signature is created. So most likely the problem is that iText needs some information for building the appearance and tries to retrieve it from some attribute that is not set. Your code fills many properties using `_settings` and `task` information. Can you share the specific values of them in a failing signing run.

Comment: @mkl I Updated my questions with the settings and the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you don't set the signer certificate using `PdfSignatureAppearance.SetCertificate`. While iText indeed does not need a certificate for the actual signing process in case of a `SignExternalContainer` use case like yours, it does need it for retrieving information about the signer to use as name and in the description in case of visible signatures with name and/or descriptions (i.e. any rendering mode but pure `GRAPHICS`).

Your setting `"RenderingMode": 1` and your stack trace `PdfSignatureAppearance.cs:Zeile 584` indicate that you are in a `NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION` use case. Thus, iText attempts to build a description, accesses its `signCertificate`, and fails because that member is `null`.

To fix this, please also set the signer certificate using `PdfSignatureAppearance.SetCertificate`.

In case of `DESCRIPTION` and `GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION` you can alternatively set the description to a pre-fabricated value using `PdfSignatureAppearance.SetLayer2Text`.

In case of `NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION`, though, iText offers no way to inject a pre-calculated name.

A more general alternative is to create the signature appearance all by yourself, simply use `GetLayer2` to retrieve a `PdfFormXObject` on which you can draw any visualization you like. In that case iText does not try and retrieve any signer information from the certificate.

Comment: I thought that if I didn't need this information with "SignExternalContainer" ... But apparently it did. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, there are ways around the need of the certificate. But if you expect iText to *automatically* create an appearance with information on the signer, there only is the certificate  to go by.

Comment: mhm another question: has this certifcate to match the certificate whitch signs the pdf afterwards?

Comment: There is no check comparing them, in a `SignExternalContainer` use case the certificate is merely used to determine name and/or description of the signer for the signature appearance. Thus, you *can* use a different certificate, but it should somehow be associated to the actual signer to give rise to a sensible appearance... Probably the certificate of the issuer?